# Using jQuery UI dialog in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui

I know there is at least 1 other post on SO dealing with this but the answer was never exactly laid out.

I am working in a WP child theme in the head.php document.  I have added this in the head:

```
<link type="text/css" href="http://www.frontporchdeals.com/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jqueryui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" />  


<?php
    wp_enqueue_style('template-style',get_bloginfo('stylesheet_url'),'',version_cache(),'screen');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-template',get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.template.js',array('jquery'),version_cache(), true);
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'); 
    wp_enqueue_script('jq-ui', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.js '); 
    wp_enqueue_script('jq-ui-min', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js' );   
?>
```

and I added this in the body:

```
<script>
    jQuery(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
    });
    </script>
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
    <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

but no dice.  My div shows as standard div.

Any ideas at all?  I know that top stylesheet should be called with enqueue but that shouldn't stop this from working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### WordPress jQuery is called in no-conflict mode:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#dialog' ).dialog();
});
```

Also jQuery UI is loading before jQuery.  You're getting 2 javascript errors:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
>
> 103Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function

The first error is from jQuery UI loading before jQuery and the second is because the $ is not recognized in no-conflict mode.

Remove any of the inline `<script src=` tags and the call to the custom.css in header php and add this function to your child theme functions.php file to load the scripts.  WordPress will put them in the right order for you.

```
add_action( 'init', 'frontporch_enqueue_scripts' );
function frontporch_enqueue_scripts() {
    if (!is_admin() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script( 'google-jquery-ui', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery-template', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.template.js',array('jquery'),version_cache(), true);
        wp_register_style( 'jquery-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css', true);
        wp_register_style( 'template-style', 'http://www.frontporchdeals.com/wordpress/wp-includes/js/jqueryui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.css', true); 
        wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-style' );
        wp_enqueue_style( ' jquery-template' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'google-jquery-ui' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-template' );
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm building a custom plugin on WP admin to insert data on custom MySQL tables. For nearly a week I was trying to do a confirmation dialog for a delete item event on a Wordpress table. After I almost lost all my hair searching for an answer, it seemed too good and simple to be true. But worked. Follows the code.

**EDIT**: turns out that the wp standard jquery wasn't working properly, and the Google hosted jQuery included in another class was making the correct calls for the JS. When I removed the unregister/register added below, ALL the other dialog calls stopped working. I don't know why this happened, or the jQuery version included in this particular WP distribution, but when I returned to the old registrations, using Google hosted scripts as seen below, everything went back to normality.

On PHP (first, register and call the script):

```
add_action('admin_init', 'init_scripts_2');

function init_scripts_2(){
    ///deregister the WP included jQuery and style for the dialog and add the libs from Google
    wp_deregister_script('jquery-ui');
    wp_register_script('jquery-ui', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.min.js');
    wp_deregister_style('jquery-ui-pepper-grinder');
    wp_register_style('jquery-ui-pepper-grinder', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.2/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui'); ///call the recently added jquery
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-pepper-grinder'); ///call the recently added style
    wp_deregister_script('prevent_delete'); ///needed the deregister. why? don't know, but worked
    ///register again, localize and enqueue your script
    wp_register_script('prevent_delete',  WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/custom_plugin/js/prevent_delete.js', array('jquery-ui'));
    wp_localize_script('prevent_delete', 'ajaxdelete', array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
    wp_enqueue_script('prevent_delete');
}
```

Next, if you're opening the dialog on a click event, like me, make sure you ALWAYS use class instead of id to identify the button or link later, on jQuery.

```
<a class="delete" href="?page=your_plugin&action=delete">Delete</a>
```

We also need to use a tag that holds the dialog text. I needed to set the style to hide the div.

```
<div id="dialog_id" style="display: none;">
    Are you sure about this?
</div>
```

Finally, the jQuery.

```
/*jslint browser: true*/
/*global $, jQuery, alert*/
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    ///on class click
    $(".delete").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); ///first, prevent the action
        var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href"); ///the original delete call

        ///construct the dialog
        $("#dialog_id").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Confirmation',
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "OK" : function () {
                    ///if the user confirms, proceed with the original action
                    window.location.href = targetUrl;
                },
                "Cancel" : function () {
                    ///otherwise, just close the dialog; the delete event was already interrupted
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        ///open the dialog window
        $("#dialog_id").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

**EDIT**: The call for the standard wp dialog style didn't work after all. The "pepper-grinder" style made the dialog appear correctly in the center of the window. I know the looks for the dialog are not very easy on the eye, but i needed the confirmation dialog and this worked just fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The dialog div is created AFTER when you're trying to act upon it. Instead, you should use:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
```

Comment: I changed out my code with what you have but no change.  I'm following the code from here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: With the exception that I've found (from other pages) in a WP install the first $ must be replaced with jQuery due to a conflict with another plugin.

Comment: Can you do `alert(jQuery)` to see if it is loaded, or check for any errors in the console?