# How do I use jQuery UI using Wordpress?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to get the jQuery UI Dialog to work with WordPress. I saw this post([Using jQuery UI dialog in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790820/using-jquery-ui-dialog-in-wordpress)) and I attempted the solution but it is not working for me. In case it matters, I am using a child theme based on the twentyeleven theme.

I put this directly in front of the wp_head() function in php:

```
function frontporch_enqueue_scripts() {
        if (!is_admin() ) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
            wp_register_script( 'google-jquery-ui', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.12/jquery-ui.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
            wp_register_script( 'jquery-template', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/jquery.template.js',array('jquery'),version_cache(), true);
            wp_register_style( 'jquery-style', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css', true); 
            wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-style' );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'google-jquery-ui' );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-template' );
        }       
    }   
    add_action( 'init', 'frontporch_enqueue_scripts' );
```

*I noticed that the twentyeleven theme or the child theme doesn't actually have that third script(template.js), but I don't think that is causing the problem.*

Then I added this at the bottom of the HEAD tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( "#markte_area" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,    
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery( "#markte_link" ).click(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
        return false;
    }); 
}); //end document ready
</script>
```

I get the following error in the Error Console when I load the page:

> **Error: $ is not a function**

The page where this is occurring is [here](http://www.dynamicpalette.com/esprit/) if that will help you diagnose the problem. Thanks for any help!

Comment: change $ to jQuery and tell me what happens then?

Comment: I changed it to jQuery and now it says "jQuery("#markte_area").dialog is not a function"

Comment: Sounds like jQuery is not loaded. Firebug will help diagnose what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

watch all the scripts you're including, in the firebug in network tab, sometimes it's a 403 error for the bad links. (clear all your cache before the checking btw).

Also does jQuery working as is?

Comment: I tested if jQuery is working as is and it works when I add an alert inside the jQuery click function.

I did check the net tab on Firebug and noticed that it looks like it is not loading in the JS files for jQuery UI although it does say it has 16 requests. I have added the url to the page where it is occurring so you can take a better look.

Thanks for all your help thus far!

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you tried disabling this "wp-cycle" plugin that I see is also doing some stuff with jQuery? Usually when I see issues like this, the first thing I do is try to see if I can narrow it down to a conflict with another plugin.

Comment: Also, I'm not a fan of the way you're enqueuing jquery-ui. The preferred method I think is to enqueue the standard WP defined `jquery-ui` script and use a plugin to redefine it to use the Google libraries. The way you're doing it now is begging for some plugin to come in and include the built in WP version of jquery ui and cause conflicts that break your site.

Answer (score 0):

I just took a look at your page. You're loading jQuery.js but not jQuery-ui.js. That is why it isn't working.

Also, make sure you're loading the correct jquery-ui.js, that includes all the modules you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/jquery-ui.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.8.6');
```